# what are the "points" of the scheme $\mathbb{Z}_8[x] /(x^2 + 7)$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, commutative-algebra, schemes

I [noticed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823440/) modulo 8 the quadratic $x^2 + 7$ is zero for four separate values $x = 1,3,5,7 \in \mathbb{Z}_8$.   The number of zeros exceeds the degree.

I would like to define the "[variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety)" $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]/(x^2 + 7)$, but $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is not a field, so I have to use [schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics)).  What is the geometric meaning of  this quadratic vanishing at 4 points?

I know the points are the [prime ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal) in the ring I have constructed.  In other worse, if $ab \in P$ then $a \in P$ or $b \in P$.  Not sure how to compute those in this ring.

The topology on this scheme is given by the [Zariski topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161884/why-zariski-topology) (I think) but I don't know what the open sets look like here.

---

[Basic understanding of Spec$(\mathbb Z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160420/basic-understanding-of-spec-mathbb-z)

[Diophantine applications of Spec?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30866/diophantine-applications-of-spec?rq=1)

**EDIT** Mumford seem to have drawn [groovy images](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/index.php/mumfords-treasure-map.html) of prime ideals in the scheme.

[image]

Comment: I would begin by making the observation that as a nilpotent element $2$ belongs to all the prime ideals. Thus the prime ideals of your ring are in 1-1 correspondence with the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$. Here, again, $x+1$ is nilpotent. Looks like there is a unique prime ideal in there.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  The "primes" would be $(1), (x+c)$ where $c \in \{ 1,3,5,7\}$.  The nilpotent $(2)$ acts like an infinitesimal, but $(x\pm1)$ is a zero divisor, not nilpotent..

Comment: @johnmangual: $(1)$ is *never* a prime, and $(x \pm 1)$ is not a zerodivisor (nor nilpotent)

Comment: @zcn $x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1)$ is $0$ in my ring $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]/(x^2 + 7)$ by definition.

Comment: @johnmangual: Yes, I meant in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @zcn I think I meant $(0)$ is prime -- I remember something the effect that a scheme basically has "one point".  Thank you.

Comment: @johnmangual: No problem. $(0)$ is not prime in this ring though - $(0)$ is prime iff the ring is a domain, which this is not. You may be thinking of generic points, which this scheme also does not have (being zero-dimensional, although since the ring is not reduced, the single point does have "fuzz")

Comment: And $x+1$ **is** nilpotent. After all
$$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1\equiv 2x-6=2(x-3)\pmod{x^2+7}.$$ This in turn implies that
$$(x+1)^6\equiv 2^3(x-3)^3=8(x-3)^3\equiv0.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** As a topological space, $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+7)) = \{(2, x+1)\}$. Notice that modulo $8$, $x^2 + 7 = x^2 - 1 = (x + 1)(x - 1)$. As pointed out by Jyrki Lahtonen, $2$ is nilpotent in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}[x]$, hence is in every prime ideal, so every prime of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+7)$ must contain $(2, x+1) = (2,x-1)$, and this is maximal, with residue field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Can you explain from this picture of $\mathrm{Spec}$ why $x^2 + 7$ should have extra roots?

Comment: @johnmangual: Being a root (in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$) of this particular polynomial is equivalent to being a unit in the base coefficient ring (strictly speaking, an inversion, but every unit has order $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$). The fact that this polynomial has "extra" roots is just saying that $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ has "many" units